# Mod Rewrite file.php? to string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have old site with links like this:

> http://domain.com/image.php?690

And I would like to change it into:

> http://domain.com/old690

I have tried many different Rules, fe.:

> RewriteRule ^image.php?(.+) old$1 [L]

EDIT: All rules looks like:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) ninja-admin/$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^image.php\?(.+) old$1 [L]

What is correct RewriteRule, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it upside down.

Put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old([0-9]+)$ image.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ ninja-admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The rule for your images is the following

```
RewriteRule ^old([0-9]+)$ image.php?$1 [L]
```

It will forward every url like `/old123` (where `123` is one or more digits) to `image.php?123`

---

EDIT: if you want to forbid direct access to `image.php?xxx` then you can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/image\.php\?([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ old%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^old([0-9]+)$ image.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ ninja-admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Dear Justin. I would like to forward `/image.php?123` to `/old123`. So the new link should be `/old123`

Comment: Well if your new link is `/old123` then it's this one that is forwarded to `/image.php?123` and not the opposite. I think you're doing some mix with it

Comment: OK. Your suggestion work from `/old123` to `/image.php?123` but no other way. I figgured out that '?' need to be escaped but \ didnt work.

Finally i do that with .php code:

`$keys = array_keys($_GET);
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http:/domain.com/old".$keys[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

I use this so `http://example.com/old4444` forwards to `http://example.com/image.php?file=4444`.

Also, the browser will keep `http://example.com/old4444` in the address bar.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?image.php$ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?old([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ image.php?marker&file=$1 [L]
```